# Elastic search sort script not working after upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch

The following sort script used to work in 0.2 but now fails in 0.9:

```
{
  "_script": {
    "script": "org.elasticsearch.common.Digest.md5Hex(doc['myId'].value + 12345)",
    "type": "string",
    "order": "asc"
  }
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
PropertyAccessException[[Error: unresolvable property or identifier: org]
```

I have seen posts suggesting creating a custom score query that does this work, so a little extra information.  I am already using a custom score query, and this sort is a secondary sort for when scores match, which can (and should) happen regularly.  The constant number in the example above is based on the person performing the search so each person who searches gets a randomized but consistent sorting and we don't always show the same results at the top to everyone.

I cannot find any information on why this is happening and how to go about fixing it while retaining the same sorting functionality.  Any help or pointing me in a new direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have to create and register a custom java script and reference it in your query (also providing "lang" : "native" parameter).
I am by no means Java expert but there is a nice tutorial on how to create such script: https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example
Check out Random Sort Script in the end as it seems to be what you need.

Comment: It feels like any non-MVEL script has to be implemented as a plugin; inline scripts are not allowed for non-MVEL scripts.  Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: I tried js also - you still have to install a plugin to enable js support but then you can do inline expressions:   "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "doc['date'].value * factor + 'anyvaluehere'",
      "type": "string",
      "params": {
        "factor": 1.1
      },
      "order": "asc",
      "lang": "js"
    }
  }

Comment: @NickLarsen inline scripting is supported for all languages other than java, for which you need to write Java code and make the compiled version available in the es classpath. The only problem is that for other languages you need to install a proper lang-plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replied to your post in the mailing list, the problem is due to the fact that the `org.elasticsearch.common.Digest`has been removed from elasticsearch. I don't think you can replace it with a single line, probably easier to write a Java native script if you are familiar with Java.

On the other hand I see you have some more details in your question here, and I've been wondering whether you could even avoid using script sorting to achieve what you want.

Your usecase makes me think about the recently added [rescore query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/rescore/), which allows to rescore top K results using a secondary query. Do take into account that the rescore is executed on each shard. So if you ask for the first 10 documents, the rescore will happen on the top 10 documents per shard, and that will influence the top 10 documents that get selected during the reduce phase. Sounds like you were more looking for changing the order of the documents that get returned, while with the rescore query those documents might change due to the rescore process itself.

The coming version, 0.90.4, will also contain random seeded ordering, which should help you with the random aspect of your sorting. Have a look at the [related issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1170) to know more.

Would be cool to combine a rescore query with a function score query that allows for random ordering.

Comment: The random seeding ordering was a good replacement.  Thanks for finding the exact commit that caused this issue in the mailing list.